# How can I share an installer generated by Visual Studio?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, installation

I made a simple checklist desktop app in Visual Studio 2015, and I'm ready to share it with the world. Problem is that I don't know how to make an installer for it that I can share online. I have an installer exported, but it is Visual Studio's default ClickOnce installer, which won't work when I remove it from its original location

Is there a way I can package it so I can upload it somewhere and then share it? Do I need to code my own, or there some add-in or tool that will do it for me?

Comment: You just make an MSI installer for it Jeff, File Menu > Add Projects > Package and Deployment> run through the Wizard and google for extra help.

Comment: Problem is, I'm using VS 2015, which doesn't have that. I've created a WiX setup project for it, but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: WiX is a PITA. VS2013 didn't have the setup project, 2015 does.

Comment: Regardless of whether 2015 should have it, my installation doesn't for some reason, and I can't afford to reinstall it. And what's a PITA?

Comment: You can get the MS Installer extension from [here.](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2015InstallerProjects). There's one for VS 2013 too.

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the MS Installer extension from [here...](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2015InstallerProjects) There's one for VS 2013 too.
(Credit to peterG for commenting this)

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the installer extension this should help you to get started, as the name implies:

https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/visual-studio/getting-started-with-setup-projects/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this older post of mine:

> What you can do,open the project as if going to edit it, just go to "Project" then "Publish(Whatever-your-work's-name-is).vb at the bottom. Then use the wizard to finish. At the end, say you saved your exe on the desktop, three files will appear.
>
> 1. "Whatever-your-work's-name-is".exe And its icon shape varies.
> 2. A folder called "Application Files"
> 3. And a "setup.exe" Its icon a like a CD on something.

For the first time, click on setup.exe and open the app. From then on, the "Whatever-your-work's-name-is".exe will open normally. I usually store all three on a zipped folder, which I upload on my website and can be downloaded from there.

To get a better example, vist my [website](http://tgamer.myfreesites.net/visual-basic).
I use this website to store my files for backup.

Comment: You can do it, but the installer doesn't work. It can't be moved from its publish location or it won't work.

Comment: @Jeff - Well I cut paste it onto my zipped file for upload. Besides, I just tried and it worked.

Comment: What you describe is the ClickOnce publisher, which the OP already said he can't get to work. I suggested he try the MSI installer extension, which adds back the MSI creation functionality which was removed from later versions of VS, replaced by InstallShield. Then there's WiX . . . Each of these has limitations, but in my personal experience the MSI extension works well for projects that don't require lots of complicated features in their installer. That said, ClickOnce can also be persuaded to work, but it won't work with clients who have eg Citrix, and uses non-standard file locations.